# apt-get not working in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm something of a Cygwin newbie, so that might be the problem, but I'm trying to install a package using `apt-get` and it's telling me there's no such command. I installed it on Windows 7.

The best I got from searching other questions here and across the net was that you need to install something specific (or run the setup file to update) when initially installing, but it's not clear to me what I need to install or run or whatever.

How do I install or update my cygwin to be able to use `apt-get` or, alternatively, how would I install packages with the basic, default installation of Cygwin that I already have?

Thank you.

Comment: re-running cygwin setup.exe lets you add/remove packages. no need for an additional tool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this : [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg)

It works just like `apt-get` in terms of command line arguments, but you will be using `apt-cyg` instead.

Comment: Oh wait,. DOH! I need to install it! Let me go try that again.

Comment: Ok, it worked! Except that I was trying to install android-tools-adb and it can't seem to find it! :( So, now I need to figure that out. I know it's outside the scope of the original question, but I'm open to suggestions if you have any. Thanks!

Comment: Googling "install android-tools-adb" gave [this](http://www.android.gs/install-android-sdk-adb-windows/) and [that](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118) :)

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin's official installer is [setup.exe](https://cygwin.com/install.html). This is the "proper" way to install Cygwin packages. There's a project called [cyg-apt](https://code.google.com/p/cyg-apt/) but it's not officially part of Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Refer *https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg* It did helped me.
To install apt-cyg package.